# Enviar parámetros ocultos POST a un archivo php y abrir un html

Tags: php, javascript, html, parámetros

Estoy intentando modificar un paso de parámetros para que no se muestren en la url y no consigo recuperarlos en la página donde se redirecciona. Os comento cómo lo tengo ahora y funciona:

En una página html al pinchar en un botón se llama a una función en archivo .js donde se redirecciona a través de window.location.href enviando por la url los parámetros a otra página html. En la nueva página html llama a través de onload a una función .js donde se envían los parámetros a un .php para hacer una consulta a la base de datos. Con los resultados de la base de datos, en javascript modifico el contenido de la página html.

Página html 1: onclick="openCountry()

```
< a class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" onclick="openCountry()">Search</a >
```

.js

```
function openCountry(){
  country = $("#listCountry").val();
  window.location.href = "searchResults.html?" + "country=" + country;

};
```

Página html 2: onload="displayResults()"

```
<body onload="displayResults()">
```

.js

```
function displayResults(){

  var country = getParameter('country');

  $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: {country: country},
        url: '../getSearchResults.php',
        success: function(data) {
            var res = JSON.parse(data);
            //añado elementos con los valores recuperados en la base de datos
            var divClass = document.createElement("div");
            document.getElementById('divResults').insertBefore(divClass, null);
            for(var i=0; i<res["datos"].length; i++){
              (function (i){
                  var divCol = document.createElement("div");
                  divCol.setAttribute("class", "col-md-4");
                  divClass.appendChild(divCol);
                  //añado más elementos con los resultados de la consulta

                };
              })(i);
            }
        },
        error: function(e, msg) { // Si no ha podido conectar con el servidor 
            // Código en caso de fracaso en el envío
            displayMessage("ERROR", "error: " + e);
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

No quiero que se muestren los parámetros en la url. He intentado llamar desde pagina1.html a php pasando los parámetros por POST y hacer la consulta pero no sé cómo coger el resultado de la consulta para abrir y modicar pagina2.html con javascript.

Comment: Con window.location.href pones los valores en la URL, quita ese código y dejarán de estar en la URL, esto lo haces para después poder obtenerlo en el JS (función displayResults), que luego ya envías por POST. Entiende que no es el POST el que te pone los parámetros en la URL, si no el window.location.href. lo que puedes hacer para pasar esos valores, es guardar los parametros en una cookie (o en SESSION con un PHP Auxiliar), después en la función displayResults, obtenerlos de la cookie/sesión en vez de los parametros de la URL.

Comment: Muchas gracias! He probado pasando cookies y funciona muy bien!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En javascript no hay manera de capturar las variables pasadas por POST ya que esas son tratadas
del lado del Servidor, por tanto lo que tienes que hacer es pasarselas a tu segunda página y tratar con ella alli
Para que funcione esto la segunda página debe ser .php, .phtml, etc (De manera que las sentencias php sean interpretadas por el
compilador, en este caso es solo una 'echo'.
Ahora, tu función openCountry cambia un poco quedando de esta forma:

```
function openCountry(){
  country = $("#listCountry").val();
  //Creo un formulario para pasar el dato a traves de POST a tu pagina 2
  $('<form action="pagina2.php" method="post"><input type="hidden" name="country" value="'+country+'" /></form>')
    .appendTo('body').submit();

};
```

Tu js en esa página debe comenzar de esta manera:

```
function displayResults(){

  var country = <?php echo $_POST['country']; ?>;
  //Si el valor de country traido desde la otra página es una cadena debes ponerlo:
  //var country = '<?php echo $_POST['country']; ?>';

  $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: {country: country},
```

Ya lo demás se mantiene